# Should I fight scrapers or ignore them all? Which is better in the long run?

Tags: seo, wordpress, scraper-sites

My website is recently scraped by several spam sites. I try to fight them and submit reports to Google and Facebook.

However, this is a tedious process. Can I just ignore them all? Which one is better in the long run?

Comment: What are they scraping? If you have a lot of high quality image content, scrapers seem to have a much bigger impact (you lose ranks in image search, etc.) compared to scrapers copying or spinning your text. I don't really understand why. Google knows the images are duplicates just like it knows with text, but sometimes these spam sites can do very well in image search.

Answer (score 2):

Keep reporting them but try not to spend too much time on it. Make sure you add copyrights to your content.

There are plugins that can stop copy and paste behavior, and if they are using your RSS feed, change it to an excerpt.

Copyscape, Cloudflare, and I am sure there are several other services that help protect your content and intellectual property.

Comment: No point in adding copyrights - you get these when you create/fix the image, and they are easily stripped/ignored.  A watermark might be more useful.  I doubt that Cloudflare help protect you protect against this, and stopping copy-paste behavior with Javascript may not do much.

Comment: I was speaking about text content.